# Limit of requests/Beautifulsoup libraries in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a website using requests and BeautifulSoup4 in Python, here is my code:

```
import requests
import bs4
result = requests.get("https://wolt.com/en/svk/bratislava/restaurant/la-donuteria-bratislava")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.content,"html5lib")
for i in soup.find_all("div", {"class": re.compile("MenuItem-module__itemContainer____.*")}):
    print(i.text)
    print()
```

When I do this with the given url I get all results. However whenever I try to scrape this url for instance:
[To be scraped](https://wolt.com/en/svk/nitra/restaurant/sakura-restaurant-1)

The result is truncated and I only get 43 results back. Is this a limitation of requests/BS4 or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you get an error for too many request, i guess if you use this request you will not get banned from the API, use it and tell me!

```
 req = Request(
        "https://drand.cloudflare.com/public/latest",
        headers={
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20130401 Firefox/31.0"
        },
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work - I get the same results as before